# Как дебажить Swing приложения?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Нужно понять код игры базируемой на `Swing`.

Так как я ещё учусь, мне очень сильно помогает встроенный отладчик, а именно
пошаговое выполнение. Как я понял со `Swing`'ом такое не проходит. Узнав из этой [статьи](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-swingtest/#resources), что есть инструменты и приемы, помогающие понять код `Swing`, написанный не вами, cкачал плагин `Swing Explorer` и установил его в `IntelliJ IDEA`, никаких изменений не почувствовал, то ли он несовместим с версии 14, то ли что то еще...

Ближе к теме, прошу помочь знающих: советом, стратегией как мне быть и неужели нет ничего под `IntelliJ IDEA`, что смогло бы позволить понять ход программы...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swing, как и всякие графические приложения, «живут» в событийно-ориентированной модели: приходит событие — вызывается его обработчик.

Поэтому пошаговое выполнение, как в утилитах командной строки, здесь принципиально не работает: большая часть кода — просто ожидание события, и его диспетчеризация. И этот код недоступен для отладки.

Поэтому вам поможет расстановка точек останова (breakpoint) в коде, который реагирует на какое-либо событие (обычно это какой-нибудь `Listener`), просмотр переменных и трассировка отдельного кода обработчика. То, что происходит между вызовами обработчиков, вам придётся додумывать самостоятельно.

Если ваши обработчики вызываются слишком часто, вам поможет отладочная печать.

---

Это всё относится, разумеется, к динамическому коду. Довольно большая часть кода на Swing — (почти) статическая, декларативная. Например, таков весь layout management. То есть реально, конечно, контейнеры и констрейнты создаются вручную, но обычно по сути в этом коде нет никакой логики.

Правильность деклараций можно проверять лишь экспериментальным путём, сравнивая их эффект с ожидаемым. (И вдумчиво читая документацию.)

Инструменты наподобие упомянутого Swing Explorer'а как раз и служат для контроля этих самых деклараций: вы написали декларацию — теперь посмотрите, как же она выглядит для Swing'а. Если инструмент по каким-то причинам не работает, вы можете сами провести работу за него (например, выставляя цветной фон различным визуальным элементам, вы увидите, где layout manager определил их границы).